# Scale Drawable - does setImageLevel dictate the scale?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I have created a small test app to try out scale drawable.

I define my drawable in xml and save it as `scale_up.xml`. I have a `main.xml` layout file with an `ImageView`. I use `android:src="@drawable/scale_up"` in the ImageView to use the drawable I created in xml. In my activity I use `myImageView.setImageLevel(some level here)` to set the level of the ImageView defined in `main.xml`. All's well and the ImageView displays the drawable defined in scale_up.

My confusion is the following:

- changing the `scaleHeight` and `scaleWidth` % in `scale_up.xml` makes no perceivable difference if the level is set at 10000
- changing the level in `setImageLevel` (between 0 and 10000) changes the size of the image - really only perceivable at around 5000. the higher the % value for scaleHeight and scaleWidth, the smaller the image (depending on the value of `setImageLevel()`)

I suppose my question/s are:

1. is it correct to use `setImageLevel()`, passing a level between 0 and 10000 -  in the activity to control the size of the drawable defined in the xml file?
2. what is the relationship between scaleHeight, scaleWidth and `setImageLevel()` - as I see it now, I may as well just set the scaleHeight and scaleWidth to 100% and then use `setImageLevel(5000)` to get a 50% scaled image - i.e increasing or reducing `setImageLevel(0 to 10000)` will change the scale - making the `scaleHeight` and `scaleWidth` % pretty pointless.

appreciate any clarification of this and perhaps an example of how to use scale drawable (defined in xml) correctly.

Answer (score -1):

1. No. setImageLevel is more like an enumerated type for images. It's for displaying different images for say, a battery charged level, or a signal bars display. You put one image under level 1 for low battery, another under 2 for medium battery, and so on. Then you use setImageLevel to switch between them. At least that's been my understanding. That said, I have no idea why it changes the scale.
2. I have no idea why any of that would be. It could be an issue with the xml editor/viewer in the ADT in eclipse, I've noticed many things display well on my phone, yet incredibly badly on my editor. I generally just work in xml for that reason.

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? That might make it easier to answer your question.